Eikonal equation in 1 D
Solving the Eikonal equation in 1 dimension with boundary values $u(0)=u(1)=0$
$$u_{x}^2-1=\epsilon u_{xx}$$
I write $v=u_{x}$, thus, I get that
$$v^{2}-1=\epsilon(v_{x})$$
$$dv/(v^2-1) = dx/\epsilon$$
$$ln( \frac{|v-1|}{|v+1|})=\frac{2}x{\epsilon} + C$$
Thus, I write
$$v=\frac{1+Ce^{2x/\epsilon}}{1-Ce^{2x/\epsilon}}$$
Now, I integrate with respect to x on both sides to get,
$$ u(x)=\int( 1 + \frac{2Ce^{2x/\epsilon}}{1-Ce^{2x/\epsilon}}) $$
$$u(x)=x-\epsilon ln|1-Ce^{2x/\epsilon}|+C_1 $$
Now using the boundary conditions, I get that
$$0= -\epsilon ln|1-C|+C_1$$
$$0=1-\epsilon ln|1-Ce^{2/\epsilon}|+C_1 $$
On Solving I get,
$$ C= \frac{e^{1/\epsilon}-1}{e^{3/\epsilon}-1} $$
$$ C_1 = \epsilon ln \frac{|e^{3/\epsilon}-e^{1/\epsilon}|}{|e^{3/\epsilon}-1|} $$
I want to estimate the behavior of the solution as $\epsilon \to 0$, but as $\epsilon \to 0$, the limit for $C$ does not exist at 0. Or should I focus on the RHL for C?
This is the vanishing viscosity solution approach. I am not sure, what am doing wrong. At $u(1/2)$ as $\epsilon \to 0$, I want to show that there is only one point wise solution.

$$u(x)=x-\epsilon \ln|1-Ce^{2x/\epsilon}|+C_1 \quad\quad\text{is OK.}$$
But this solution isn't complete.
$v=\frac{1+Ce^{2x/\epsilon}}{1-Ce^{2x/\epsilon}}$ can be also written as $v=\frac{C+e^{2x/\epsilon}}{C-e^{2x/\epsilon}}$ which leads to the missing solution :
$$u(x)=-x-\epsilon \ln|1-C\,e^{-2x/\epsilon}|+C_1$$
Below we suppose $\epsilon>0$ and $\epsilon\to 0$.
The solution must not tend to infinity when $\epsilon\to 0$. As a consequence the solution becomes :
$$\begin{cases}
u(x)=x-\epsilon \ln|1-Ce^{2x/\epsilon}|+C_1\quad\quad x<0\\
u(x)=-x-\epsilon \ln|1-C\,e^{-2x/\epsilon}|+C_1\quad\quad x>0\\
u(x)=-\epsilon \ln|1-C|+C_1\quad\quad x=0
\end{cases}$$
With conditions :$\quad u(0)=u(1)=0$ :
$$\begin{cases}
u(1)=0=-1-\epsilon \ln|1-C\,e^{-2/\epsilon}|+C_1\\
u(0)=0=-\epsilon \ln|1-C|+C_1
\end{cases}$$
$C=\frac{1-e^{1/\epsilon}}{1-e^{-1/\epsilon}}\quad;\quad C_1=\epsilon\ln\left( 1-\frac{1-e^{1/\epsilon}}{1-e^{-1/\epsilon}}\right)$
$$\begin{cases}
u(x)=x-\epsilon \ln|1-Ce^{2x/\epsilon}|+C_1\quad\quad x<0\\
u(x)=-x-\epsilon \ln|1-C\,e^{-2x/\epsilon}|+C_1\quad\quad x>0\\
u(0)=0
\end{cases}$$
